# JPA does not refresh attributes after insert

Tags: java, jpa

If I add new record to database ( by application or manual by sqldeveloper) 
I don't see it in application. I must restart server to fetch this new-added object. Have you any ideas why ?

```
public TYPE getItem(Long id){
        if(id!=null){
            try{
                em=EMFactory.createEntityManager();
                return em.find(entityClass, id);
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error("Error while getItem", e);
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }finally {
                if(em!=null)
                    em.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For example, i enter address ".../action?id=34" then run getItem method and object should be fetched from database. But if I modify any properties of this object, after start application, then after invoke this method I get old propery of this application.

```
1. UserData.name=lucas
2. appication starting
3. I change name to tom UserData.name=tom
4. refresh website -> run getItem()
5. still name = lucas
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're describing, in part because your example doesn't seem to match the problem you stated.  I can say, however, that your manner of obtaining an entity is highly suspicious.  If you close the `EntityManager` from which you obtained a given entity, then that entity becomes detached.  Changes to it cannot and will not be persisted unless you first (re)attach it to an appropriate EM.  You must use the same EM for the life of a given transaction, and you *can* use an EM for multiple transactions.

Comment: Describe your specific problem, add code to reproduce the issue, create MCVE, explain what did you tried to solve it, otherwise your question is off-topic on SO.